# Configurable Swatches in Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: color-swatches, swatches

I added all the steps possible to make the configurable swatches functionality in the default theme of magento as per above answer link.

My Question is I have made all the steps in a correct way and the images replaced the drop-down in the product details page. But it is not replacing the text link to the images and also image switch over is not working.!

[image]

Not working in layered navigation and showing only the text links instead of image swatches.

[image]

Comment: This is a quite broad question. But I don't think it should get closed.

Comment: I know it is quite broad in nature. Here i have got a link regarding this. I would like to know whether it would be working or not? The link is https://www.bemaged.com/en/blog/use-magento-swatches-in-custom-theme/